# How to cancel a Task in SonarQube that is In Progress?

Tags: sonarqube, background-task

I am trying to kill a background task that is in progress in m sonarqube.

This task is doing a scan on a project.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You have posted the analysis information to SonarQube yourself.

Comment: Somebody ran a background task and has been at it for days now.

Comment: Having the same problem, and it looks like its also blocking the new pending tasks, Sonar 5.6.6 in my case

Comment: Also having the same problem with four pending tasks that are running for 5 days and therefore keep on queueing all the other tasks for the same project. 

Would it be possible to cancel these processes by removing some files or by manually modifying some field in the database?

Comment: One of my SonarQube Job is running more than 300-mins. I think it is hanging, But seems no way to stop (or) cancel the same. The only way is that I need to wait until it finishes?

Answer (score 2):

I connected to sonarqube DB and I executed this query to retrieve the "in progress" job

`select * from ce_queue where status<>'PENDING';`

Then I deleted the record `delete from ce_queue where id=2325;`

Comment: Does not work : the task disappears from the tasks list but subsequents tasks stays 'PENDING' forever. Eventually you still have to reboot the server. And because there are forever pending tasks, reboot from the web UI won't work. You'll have to force reboot from CLI. (sonarqube version 7.8)

Answer (score 1):

In-progress tasks cannot be canceled for the moment

Comment: What is recommended way of removing hanging background tasks here?

Comment: @DanielMagnusson why are these tasks hanging ?

Comment: Don't know, Sonarqube acting up? =)  But we rebooted the server and waited an hour or so and it went away.  Not optimal but..worked.

Comment: You should check logs/es.log next time and check for WARN/ERROR

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam Sooo.... This is a year and a half old and we still can't cancel a task?

Comment: @IEatBagels Indeed ! Feel free to open a new thread on https://community.sonarsource.com/

Comment: ‍♂️ this app is terrible, I have a task that's been stuck for hours...

Comment: @GerardoBuenrostroGonzález Feel free to open a thread on the community support here : https://community.sonarsource.com/c/help/sq/10

Answer (score 0):

I also continue to have this problem with `Enterprise EditionVersion 7.2.1 (build 14109)`. It's ridiculous that this problem has persisted for years and it's a big deal because it takes one of your workers out of the pool.

The only way I have found to kill the task is to delete the entire project that is associated with the task. Restarting the service / rebooting (to catch other processes, etc) / none of this helped.

**Deleting the project kills the task**

you're welcome